# Return a html page with first request to a Json Rpc Dispatcher server running locally at port 5000

Tags: perl, rpc, json-rpc, plack

I have  Json Rpc Dispatcher Server running in my local host at port 5000  I need to get a html index page when i visit

```
http://localhost:5000
```

here is the app.psgi
    use JSON::RPC::Dispatcher;

```
my $rpc = JSON::RPC::Dispatcher->new;

$rpc->register( 'ping', sub { return 'pong' } );
$rpc->register( 'echo', sub { return $_[0] } );

sub add_em {
  my @params = @_;
  my $sum = 0;
  $sum += $_ for @params;
  return $sum;
}

$rpc->register( 'sum', \&add_em );

# Want to do some fancy error handling? 
sub guess {
  my ($guess) = @_;
  if ($guess == 10) {
    return 'Correct!';
  }
  elsif ($guess > 10) {
    die [ 986, 'Too high.', $guess];
  }
  else {
    die [ 987, 'Too low.', $guess ];
  }
}
$rpc->register( 'guess', \&guess );
```

For now it only returns json with either a GET guess or sum method request.

I need to have a GET request that will return a html page and load some Javascript maybe with the root request

```
http://localhost:5000/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`JSON-RPC 2.0` Specification](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#response_object):

> When a rpc call is made, the Server MUST reply with a Response, except for in the case of Notifications. **The Response is expressed as a single JSON Object**, ...

So its not possible to get a html page from a JSON::RPC Server.

Comment: Okay i will see a way to get around that.